# Not using > makes all the difference in opening gedit through terminal w/o errors or locking the terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, gedit, functions, stdout

I have been experimenting with using terminal to open gedit with any type of file it is capable of using and not having the terminal blocked until the file is closed OR have any error messages in the terminal output.

Essentially a difference of:

```
/dev/null
    or
>/dev/null
```

This opens a text file through terminal and doesnt lock it and doesnt show any error messages.

```
function gedit {
    sudo -H gedit "$@" /dev/null 2>&1 &
    clear;
}
```

This does not work and is the inverse of the method above.

```
function gedit {
    sudo -H gedit "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    clear;
}
```

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: You are right the -H is meant for Sudo. I will make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand what a command in a terminal window is doing you need to start from basic shell syntax. The `>` character has a very specific function and hence its presence makes a fundamental difference on that level.

One fundamental point first: adding `sudo` indiscriminately like that is dangerous and I recommend against it. It is much too easy to forget you are working with `root` privilege if the `sudo` is hidden away inside a function.

In your first version:

```
sudo -H gedit "$@" /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

the `sudo` command is called with the `-H` option and the argument `gedit "$@" /dev/null` where `"$@"` is replaced by the list of parameters passed to the function.
So `gedit` is run as user `root` with a list of files to edit which comprises all the files given by the user plus the file `/dev/null`.
(Whether editing `/dev/null` makes any sense is beyond the scope of this explanation.)
The element `2>&1` does nothing in this version since standard output and standard error already go to the same destination anyway. The element `&` puts the whole command into the background so it frees up the terminal window again. As a consequence, it will however cause `sudo` or `gedit` to block should they try to write anything to standard output or standard error.

In your second version:

```
sudo -H gedit "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

the `sudo` command is called with the `-H` option and the argument `gedit "$@"` where `"$@"` is replaced by the list of parameters passed to the function as before.
So `gedit` is run as user `root` with exactly the list of files to edit given by the user.
The element `>` redirects the command's standard output to the following file `/dev/null`, effectively discarding it, and the element `2>&1` redirects standard error to the same destination.
The element `&` puts the whole command into the background as before, but since standard output and standard error have been redirected this time the programs will not block on writing there.

Once you've understood that fundamental functional difference you can start analyzing why each version behaves the way it does and how to change behaviour you don't like. For example, `sudo` may try to prompt for a password which conflicts with being put into the background. If you want to cling to `sudo` against my advice there are ways to work around that by separating the password checking and program running steps of `sudo` via the `-v` and `-n` options.

Comment: That is exactly what I was wanting to know. Thank you for precisely spelling out the logical behavior of each step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be a few things, because you're outputting all errors to `/dev/null`, you won't be able to read those errors.

I would recommend moving the `-H` flag before the command you intend to execute privileged.  I think `sudo` is picky about these things.  (ie: `sudo -H COMMAND_HERE`).

It is likely that your current shell hasn't elevated to `sudo`, and you're being asked to enter your password.

```bsh
function gedit {
    sudo sleep 0
    sudo -H gedit "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
    clear
}
```

You can try to issue `sleep 0` or `echo` just to get the sudo prompt.  If you already typed in your password, then this should still work.

Or, if you have `gedit` set up in your `sudoers`, then you can remove the `sudo sleep 0` line, but either way, you need to fix the `-H` flag for `sudo`.

Comment: I have edited the sudoers file to remove the prompt for my password as I am on a very secure container network. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Please see the other changes, such as `-H` flag.  Your `sudoers` likely won't honor the command because the `-H` is out of place, and it is likely asking you for your password.  Very easy to test and see just by getting rid of `/dev/null 2>&1` portion of the function.